How can I sort a yaml file based on the value of a particular key
Part 1 : I have a yaml file with many blocks defining input text and the text its replaces with.  Each block has a trigger key and the value of that trigger, a replacement key and the value the trigger is replaced with and a comment line: e.g.
# ::;waf::web application firewall
  - trigger: ";waf"
    replace: "web application firewall"

# ::;m$::Microsoft
  - trigger: ";m$"
    replace: "Microsoft"

# ::;sf::Salesforce
  - trigger: ";sf"
    replace: "Salesforce"

I'd like to sort the blocks into order based on the value of the trigger key
# ::;m$::Microsoft
  - trigger: ";m$"
    replace: "Microsoft"

# ::;sf::Salesforce
  - trigger: ";sf"
    replace: "Salesforce"

# ::;waf::web application firewall
  - trigger: ";waf"
    replace: "web application firewall"

If the comments mess things up then I can use a reg exp to move the comment from a preceding line to an inline comment on the end of the trigger line.  What I'm trying to avoid is using a regexp to turn the three lines into one, then sort, then split back into three lines again because...
...Part 2:
I have a similar file, again with many blocks.  Each block has AT LEAST a trigger key, a replacement key and a comment line but may also have other key value pairs as well.  Each block always starts with a trigger.
I'd like to sort the blocks into order based on the value of the trigger key but keep the blocks.  Doing a regexp to concatenate an unknown and variable number of key value pairs is making my head hurt.
My chosen editor is VScodium, I tried the YAML sort extension but it sorts on the key names, not the key values or at least it does for how I've got it configured.  I'm happy with a solution in bash, sed, awk or whatever but one-liners (as opposed to a full multiline code block with nested loops) would be preferred if possible.  I want to see what the most elegant/efficient way of achieving this is. Please :-)

By using sed and sort, try this: sed ':a;N;/\n$/!{$!ba};s/\n/\o01/g;s/- trigger:/\o2/' file.yaml | sort -t $'\2' -k2 | sed '$!{/\o1$/!s/$/\o1/};$s/\o1$//;s/\o1/\n/g;s/\o2/- trigger:/'

I allowed myself to turn the comments into keys. That is:
- trigger: ";waf"
  replace: "web application firewall"
  comment: ::;waf::web application firewall

- trigger: ";m$"
  replace: "Microsoft"
  comment: ::;m$::Microsoft

- trigger: ";sf"
  replace: "Salesforce"
  comment: ::;sf::Salesforce

If that works for you, then using:
cat foo.yml | yq '.|=sort_by(.trigger)'

you will get what you want:
- trigger: ";m$"
  replace: "Microsoft"
  comment: ::;m$::Microsoft
- trigger: ";sf"
  replace: "Salesforce"
  comment: ::;sf::Salesforce
- trigger: ";waf"
  replace: "web application firewall"
  comment: ::;waf::web application firewall

If you wonder, yq can be found here.

.|= makes no sense, and providing the file directly would allow yq to seek. yq 'sort_by(.trigger)' foo.yml

yq is installable using apt get insall yq under Debian bookworm!

The mikefarah/yq implementation can handle comments in YAML files (while the other yq implementation, kislyuk/yq, can't because internally it converts to JSON, which disallows comments).
To make mikefarah/yq associate a comment to the right item, the comment has to sit in a place that "belongs" to that item. In your case, you have a top-level array with maps (aka objects) as its items, and you want each comment to be associated to an array item. Thus, either attach the comments to any part of the map item; here's an example using the trigger field:
  - trigger: ";waf" # ::;waf::web application firewall
    replace: "web application firewall"

  - trigger: ";m$" # ::;m$::Microsoft
    replace: "Microsoft"

  - trigger: ";sf" # ::;sf::Salesforce
    replace: "Salesforce"

Or use the array's index itself, represented by the - symbol (this way, the comment is associated to the array item but not to any part of the map contained):
  - # ::;waf::web application firewall
    trigger: ";waf"
    replace: "web application firewall"

  - # ::;m$::Microsoft
    trigger: ";m$"
    replace: "Microsoft"

  - # ::;sf::Salesforce
    trigger: ";sf"
    replace: "Salesforce"

In both cases, all you need to do is to call the sort_by() function (which acts on the top-level context, i.e. the array) with the .trigger value as the sorting criterion:
yq 'sort_by(.trigger)' input.yaml

This will sort the array's items (including the associated comments), regardless how big each item is (or how deep it is nested). The output depends on the input. The two examples from above respectively convert to:
- trigger: ";m$" # ::;m$::Microsoft
  replace: "Microsoft"
- trigger: ";sf" # ::;sf::Salesforce
  replace: "Salesforce"
- trigger: ";waf" # ::;waf::web application firewall
  replace: "web application firewall"

and
- # ::;m$::Microsoft
  trigger: ";m$"
  replace: "Microsoft"
- # ::;sf::Salesforce
  trigger: ";sf"
  replace: "Salesforce"
- # ::;waf::web application firewall
  trigger: ";waf"
  replace: "web application firewall"


You can use Ruby with its built-in YAML parser:
ruby -r yaml -e 'puts YAML.load($<.read).sort_by{|d| d["trigger"]}.to_yaml' file.yaml  

Prints:
---
- trigger: ";m$"
  replace: Microsoft
- trigger: ";sf"
  replace: Salesforce
- trigger: ";waf"
  replace: web application firewall

If you want to keep the comments you can to do a decorate/sort/undecorate:
ruby -r yaml -e 'puts "---"+$<.read.
    scan(/^\s*#[\s\S]+?(?=(?:^\s*#)|\z)/).
    map{|s| [s, YAML.load(s)[0] ] }.
    sort_by{|a| a[1]["trigger"] }.
    map(&:first).join
' file.yaml

Prints:
---
# ::;m$::Microsoft
  - trigger: ";m$"
    replace: "Microsoft"

# ::;sf::Salesforce
  - trigger: ";sf"
    replace: "Salesforce"

# ::;waf::web application firewall
  - trigger: ";waf"
    replace: "web application firewall"

Or if you know that your YAML bits always are in paragraphs (two or more \n between each block to be sorted), you can lose the regex:
ruby -r yaml -e 'puts "---"
    puts $<.read.split(/\R{2,}/).
    map{|s| [s, YAML.load(s)[0] ] }.
    sort_by{|a| a[1]["trigger"] }.map(&:first).join("\n\n")
' file.yaml
# same output


Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and sorted_in if each trigger value is unique within the input:
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F '\n' '
    { recs[$2] = $0 }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for ( i in recs ) {
            print recs[i]
        }
    }
' file
# ::;m$::Microsoft
  - trigger: ";m$"
    replace: "Microsoft"

# ::;sf::Salesforce
  - trigger: ";sf"
    replace: "Salesforce"

# ::;waf::web application firewall
  - trigger: ";waf"
    replace: "web application firewall"

otherwise change recs[$2] = $0 to recs[$2] = ($2 in recs ? recs[$2] ORS : "") $0.
The above assumes the input looks like the example the OP provided, including that the "trigger" line is always the 2nd one in each empty-line-separated record.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub that has nothing to do with my answer so please delete this comment and post it as your own answer (or a comment under the question if you insist on making it a comment).

I clearly think the correct way is to use yaml libraries, by using yq using awk, ruby or sed is counterproductive.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Posting a sed pipeline under an awk answer doesn't come close to making that opinion clear - quite the reverse. If you don't think people should use sed then just say that rather than posing a solution using sed in multiple comments.

1 thing learned : Ruby is on my Mac :-O
1 thing remembered : yq is a tool I found a couple of years back and thought really useful but didn't have a use for it at the time
Solution I've used
brew update
brew install yq
yq '.matches |= sort_by(.trigger)' matches.yml >newmatches.yml

So much as ruby appears to be more flexible, as mentioned in the comments above, yq seems to be using the right tool and as you can see from the solution is a lot easier...
... although the comments are left in the same order as the original text so do get separated from the text they were originally associated with and are mixed up
